# Problemas con textarea

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo este código:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="texto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Comentario</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="texto" name="texto" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu comentario" required>{{old('texto')}}</textarea>

        @if ($errors->has('texto'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('texto') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto es un fragmento de un formulario en el que permito que un usuario escriba un comentario en una noticia.
Las condiciones en el Request estan en este código:

```
public function messages(){
    return[
        'texto.required'=>'No puedes dejar este campo vacío',
        'texto.min'=>'Tu comentario debe tener como mínimo 10 caracteres'
    ];
}

public function rules(){
    return[
        'texto'=>'required|min:10'
    ];
}
```

En otros tipos de cajas de formulario si intento darle a crear la nueva fila sin cumplir las normas, me devuelve al formulario con las cajas marcadas en rojo y con el mensaje de error, pero en el caso del textarea el mensaje de error no aparece ni el contorno rojo.
¿Hay alguna solución?

Más información:
Este es el formulario completo:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-25">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Publicar un comentario</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('comentario.publicar',$articulo)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="articulo_id" value="{{ $articulo->id }}"/>

                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}"/>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="texto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Comentario</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="texto" name="texto" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu comentario" required>{{old('texto')}}</textarea>

                                @if ($errors->has('texto'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('texto') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Publicar comentario
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esta es la función con la que introduzco el comentario:

```
public function escribir(ComentarioRequest $request, Articulo $articulo){
    $comentario=Comentario::create($request->all());
    return back()->with('message',['success','Su comentario esta publicado.']);
}
```

Y este es ComentarioRequest:

```
class ComentarioRequest extends FormRequest{
    public function authorize(){
        return true;
    }

    public function messages(){
        return[
            'texto.required'=>'No puedes dejar este campo vacío',
            'texto.min'=>'Tu comentario debe tener como mínimo 5 caracteres'
        ];
    }

    public function rules(){
        return[
            'texto'=>'required|min:5'
        ];
    }
}
```

¿Cómo deberia modificar el código entonces?

Answer (score 1):

El textarea necesita la clase form-control y la etiqueta form necesita la clase needs-validation y, una vez validado, añadir was-validated. Con eso debería funcionar.

Además veo conveniente que no envíes el id de usuario a través de un campo del formulario, ya que es fácilmente modificable. Tampoco el de articulo ya que tienes acceso a él en el controlador a través de la url.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-25">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Publicar un comentario</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <form class="needs-validation{!! $errors->any() ? ' was-validated' : '' !!}" method="POST" action="{{route('comentario.publicar',$articulo)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="texto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Comentario</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <textarea id="texto" class="form-control" name="texto" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu comentario" required>{{old('texto')}}</textarea>

                            @if ($errors->has('texto'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('texto') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Publicar comentario
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
class ComentarioRequest extends FormRequest{
    public function authorize(){
        return auth()->check();
    }

    public function messages(){
        return[
            'texto.required'=>'No puedes dejar este campo vacío',
            'texto.min'=>'Tu comentario debe tener como mínimo 5 caracteres'
        ];
    }

    public function rules(){
        return[
            'texto'=>'required|min:5'
        ];
    }
}

public function escribir(ComentarioRequest $request, Articulo $articulo){
    $comentario=Comentario::create([
        'id_usuario' => auth()->id(),
        'id_articulo' => $articulo->id,
        'texto' => $request->get('texto'),
    ]);
    return back()->with('message',['success','Su comentario esta publicado.']);
}
```

Comment: Así he incluido. Ahora el "textarea" queda marcado en color verde indicando error, pero no aparece aún ningun mensaje indicando cual ha sido el fallo.

Comment: Y he probado con otro proyecto que tenia y tambien me ocurre este fallo de las cajas verdes.